# What does None in a function mean / optional fields

Tags: python

I am trying to use the function below.  Mostly when i call this function I just pass in the report_type but a few of the report calls wants a start_date.  Questions

1. Does the None in the definition of function mean that the field is optional

   ```
   def request_report(self, report_type, start_date=None, end_date=None, marketplaceids=()):
   data = dict(Action='RequestReport',
               ReportType=report_type,
               StartDate=start_date,
               EndDate=end_date)
   data.update(utils.enumerate_param('MarketplaceIdList.Id.', marketplaceids))
   return self.make_request(data)
   ```
2. I normally call the function with one of the lines below depending on if I am passing a start_date.  Other then having a series of 'if' statements for each request type is there a good way to call this function and only pass a specific variable if it is populated?  Over time I will be adding more optional parameters and done want a giant 'if' statement

   ```
   requested_report=report_api.request_report(report_type=report_name, start_date=starting_date)
   requested_report=report_api.request_report(report_type=report_name)
   ```

Comment: So how do you determine that `starting_date` is not needed? Isn't that an `if` statement too?

Comment: for each report type that  I request I have a row in a mysql database.  So I added a column start_date.  Plan to check is string is not empty and then use the code from your answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=...` part gives a parameter a *default value*. Here that's `None`, and that does mean the parameter is optional when calling the function. If you don't specify it, the default is used. See [*Default Argument Values*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) in the Python tutorial, as well as the [reference documentation for function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> When one or more parameters have the form *parameter = expression*, the function is said to have “default parameter values.” For a parameter with a default value, the corresponding argument may be omitted from a call, in which case the parameter’s default value is substituted.

When calling such a function, you could pass in the same value as the default, to this specific function that makes no difference; so when there is no `starting_date`, you can pass in `None`:

```
start_date = starting_date or None  # when determining the starting date, default to None
requested_report=report_api.request_report(
    report_type=report_name,
    start_date=starting_date
)
```

Another option is to set any optional keyword arguments in a dictionary, then pass those in with the `**` call syntax to [unpack the dictionary as keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
kwargs = {}
if ...:  # test that decides if start_date is needed
    kwargs['start_date'] = starting_date  # expression to set the start date

requested_report=report_api.request_report(
    report_type=report_name, **kwargs)
```

It is fine for the `kwargs` dictionary to be empty.

Comment: there is so much helpful knowledge here.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a `default parameter`.

> Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html) is the doc on method definition.
[Here is additional information](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/)

Comment: *No, It doesn't mean optional*? So what, in your book, would optional *mean*? It **is** optional in the call, in that you don't have to specify a value for that argument.

Comment: I agree, let me change my answer.